# Convert a Multi-Dimensional Array to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

Playing with a quick concept. Hopefully the answer is pretty simple, my attempt is just failing here for some reason.

Let's say I have an array such as:

`var items = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]];`

And I'm trying to flip the data around, so it converts it into:

`var items_converted = [[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8,11],[3,6,9,12]];`

This much is completed. Now, with my new multidimensional array, I want to push each internal array's contents to an HTML table row:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...
```

#### Play here: http://jsfiddle.net/XDFd2/

I tried doing it with two `for-loops`, but it doesn't seem to be appending the `<tr>` or `</tr>`.

```
var items = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]];
var items_converted = [[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8,11],[3,6,9,12]];
var table = $('#table');

for(var i=0; i<items_converted.length; i++){
        if(i==0){
            table.append('<tr>');
        }
    for(var j=0; j<items_converted[i].length; j++){
        table.append('<td>'+items_converted[i][j]+'</td>');
        if(j===items_converted[0].length-1){
            table.append('</tr');
        }
    }
}
```

I feel I'm missing something very simple here... perhaps the order that the loops are processing?

Any help is appreciated.

#### Play here: http://jsfiddle.net/XDFd2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/XDFd2/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use `append()` like `document.write()`. That's a wrong approach. You should look at the DOM starting at your `table` node and append nodes for each row and cell.

Basically a `$('<tr>')` to create a row, followed by an `table.append()` call to add it to the DOM. Likewise for the cells.

```
var items = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]];
var items_converted = [[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8,11],[3,6,9,12]];
var table = $('#table');
var row, cell;

for(var i=0; i<items_converted.length; i++){
     row = $( '<tr />' );
    table.append( row );
    for(var j=0; j<items_converted[i].length; j++){
        cell = $('<td>'+items_converted[i][j]+'</td>')
        row.append( cell );
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XDFd2/2/)

Comment: *Facepalm* Thanks Sirko!

Comment: @NicholasHazel Instead of grabbing the text and then creating a new node with it, you could also just rearrange the old cells. Shlightly different code, but should have some performance gain for larger datasets.